# Qt development and the necessity of OpenGL with QML pages

Tags: qt, opengl, qml

Is OpenGL mandatory in order to run a Qt application made of QML pages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with `Qt Quick 2.0` OpenGL is a mandatory requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Well, an implementation of OpenGL ES 2 is mandatory for Qt Quick 2, but that doesn't mean you need to use native OpenGL. On Windows you really should be using ANGLE, since on many Windows systems the installed OpenGL is either too old or broken.